# dotnet core webapi calling .net webapi2

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-2.0, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am calling a .NET WebApi2 endpoint from a dotnet core webapi. When I debug into the .NET WebApi2 **POST** endpoint, my value is always null. Is this not possible to do?

When I call the GET endpoint with an ID, the ID is passed with no issues.

I have used both Postman and Fiddler to debug. Whenever I pass my JSON object from Postman to the .NET WebApi2 **POST** endpoint, my **value is populated**.

Beyond frustrated as this seems pretty simple. :,(

**Updated to include code**

dotnet core web api (calling from Postman)

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task PostAsync([FromBody] string value)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var jsonObject = new JObject();
        jsonObject.Add("text", "Rich");


        var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:54732/api/Rich", jsonObject);
        var responseResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    }
```

**.NET WebApi2 (JObject is always null)**

```
// POST: api/Rich
    public void Post(JObject value) 
    {

    }
```

Comment: It's worth including both the code you're using in you ASP.NET Core project and an example of the request that you're making using Postman. It's going to be very difficult to help without that information.

Comment: Please include your code as a [mcve] so we can provide more help. It’s hard to provide any analysis without code :-)

Comment: please include code examples and what you have tried as pointed by others here.

Answer (score 0):

This boils down to using `JObject` basically. For your older Web Api action, `JObject` works merely because you're posting JSON, and JObject is a dynamic. However, that is an entirely incorrect approach. You should be binding to a concrete class that represents the JSON being posted. That said, you may or may not be able to change anything there, and its not *technically* the source of your current issue.

The actual source is that you're attempting to send a `JObject`, which is not doing what you think it is. Again, JObject is a dynamic. It has accessors to parse and access the underlying JSON, but it does not actually expose the members of that JSON object directly. As a result, if you attempt to serialize it, you won't get anything usable from it. Passing it to `PostAsJsonAsync` causes it to be serialized.

What you actually need is something like:

```
var jsonObject = new { text = "Rich" };
```

Then, what you're passing to `PostAsJsonAsync` will be an anonymous object *with actual members that can be serialized*.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your suggestion did not work. I even created a Model class in the .NET WebApi2 project. The value is still NULL. Fiddler shows the value is there on the HTTP POST request.

Answer (score 0):

My **"REAL"** issue turned out to be **Transfer-Encoding: chunked** was being sent in the request header.

Here is my corrected code (dotnet core web api):

```
 public async Task PostAsync([FromBody] JObject value)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
                               MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var jsonObject = new { variable1 = "Rich" };


        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        content.Headers.ContentLength = json.Length;
        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:54732/api/Rich", content);

        var responseResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    }
```

Here is my .NET WebApi2 code:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]RichTest value)
    {
        return Ok(value.variable1 + " done");
    }

public class RichTest
{
    public string variable1 { get; set; }
}
```

When I set the content.Headers.ContentLength, the **Transfer-Encoding: chunked** is removed. Now my code is working!!

I am still curious why the original PostAsJsonAsync does not work...